# Selenium test - OK/Cancel popup disappearing immediately

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Odd one here. When testing this manually I click the delete button, wait for the popup
[image]
Then I click OK and the record is removed as expected.
But when I try to do the same in Java/Selenium it goes like this->

```
WebElement element = _driver.findElement(By.id("btnDeletePatient"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)_driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

or

```
_driver.findElement(By.id("btnDeletePatient")).click();
```

Both have the same response, the OK/Cancel popup will appear and then immediately vanish.

This is the code for the button

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cpContentLeft$btnPatient" 
value="Delete User" onclick="return userDelete();" 
id="ctl00_cpContentLeft_btnPatient" 
tabindex="81" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mr-3">
```

And this is the code for the function userDelete

```
 function userDelete() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this user?")) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also I have now tried the same in Edge, same thing so this does not appear to be a Chrome issue.

Anyone got any ideas what is causing this please?

Further tests as follows.
I place a breakpoint just at the point the script will click the delete run and run the script. The page loads as expected and I get to the problem point.

1. I manually click the Delete button, the popup appears and then stays until I click cancel.
2. Using this code I step through and the popup appears and then instantly disappears.

   _driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cpContentLeft_btnDelete")).click();
3. Using this code the response is the say as 2.

   _driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cpContentLeft_btnDeletePatient")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
4. Then I try a double click and nothing happens.
   On all tests I see no errors in the console.

Comment: Have you looked into using the IAlert interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error and I tried to adjust the browser window size and my problem was resolved.

```
webdriver.ExecuteScript($"document.body.style.zoom='100%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are clicking the delete button before page loads completely, that is why pop is disappearing suddenly. please add wait before clicking delete button.

**Steps:**

1. Load the page completely (add wait here)
2. Click the delete button
3. click Okay button.

please add some more codes here and screenshots too. that would be more helpful

Comment: Hi, the page is fully loading before the Click. I even placed a breakpoint on the line before the click. At this point I manually clicked the button and it worked as expected, so I cancelled and then allowed the automation click to happen, the popup again appeared and disappeared straight away.

Comment: please paste the exact error ?

Comment: There is no error. The popup appears and then disappears before the script can click on it.

Comment: then your script is clicking the okay i guess

Comment: Yep, all sorted thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a java script alert. In selenium, we have specific way to handle alert. You do not need to click on ok. You can first wait for alert to be present. If it is present, then switch to that alert.

Then, We have specific methods to handle alerts in selenium.

alert.accept() clicks on ok.

alert.dismiss() clicks on cancel.

**Sample code from selenium documentation:**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("See a sample prompt")).click();

//Wait for the alert to be displayed and store it in a variable
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

//Type your message
alert.sendKeys("Selenium");

//Press the OK button
alert.accept();

//Press the Cancel button
alert.dismiss();

//Store the alert in a variable for reuse
String text = alert.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for info but the problem is that when automation clicks the button the popup will appear and then disappear immediately, there is nothing to wait for. If I manually click the button then the popup appears and remains, I can then continue.

Comment: Try these 3 -> 1. Put a hardcode wait after clicking and comment out rest of the code? Check what exactly is happening? 2. Change click to doubleClick()  3. Try to use selenium click method instead of java script executor

Comment: Did you check with selenium click and double click methods instead of java script click?

Comment: I have just updated the main thread

Comment: Ok found it

The issue was within the chromedriver, this line fixed it

chromeOptions.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "ignore");

Now the popup remains until actioned in the script.

We live and learn, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Something new to learn. You can post that as a answer, so that it can help rest of the community.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it

The issue was within the chromedriver, this line fixed it

chromeOptions.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "ignore");

Now the popup remains until actioned in the script.

We live and learn, thanks for all your help.